# integrated Oauth input data in C# code

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0

I would like to retrieve information from an [API](http://api.searchmetrics.com/api-calls/service/ResearchOrganicGetCountDomainKeywordHistoric). For this aim I have a *Cosumer key* and *Consumer secret*. If I use a Rest Consol to test my input data, I get the answer.

I would like to implement this in c#. I have written this code:

```
 var url = "http://api.searchmetrics.com/v1/ResearchOrganicGetListSeoVisibilityHistoric.json?url=searchmetrics.com&countrycode=us&date_from=20121001&date_to=20121231";
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            var oAuthHeader = @"OAuth oauth_signature_method=""HMAC - SHA1"" oauth_version=""2.0""  oauth_consumer_key=""xxxxd7c0a777f1ccxxxx7ab7101a57da3182xxxx"" oauth_consumer_secret=""xxxx95e74834exxxx9d546f78019c2cd8f32xxxx""";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.ReadLine();
```

If I run this code, I get the **(500) Internal Server Error**

How should I change my code to solve this internal error?

Comment: Are you sure that Authorization header should have consumer secret in it? Is it the same header which is being beheaded generated by the rest console?

Comment: actually not. The Rest Consol generate another header: `Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" oauth_version="2.0" url="searchmetrics.com" countrycode="us" date_from="20121001" date_to="20121231" oauth_nonce="UDO6L" oauth_timestamp="1506016926" oauth_consumer_key="8cxxxxxxa777f1cc20817ab7101a57da318287df" oauth_signature="zXtKAR8ZGH9ufNuTg7rNQgVINmc%3D"`. If I put it in my C# code, I recieve the same error. Do you know, what should I put in my c# code?

Comment: You need to know how to generate signature for OAuth header. And I doubt if this is what you are doing is OAuth2. But you notice that there are different things in the OAuth header. They all take part in signature genration. There is a standard way if generating OAuth1 signature. But you need to check the documentation of API provider too to understand and implement it properly. http://api.searchmetrics.com/start#basic-structure

Comment: https://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/